# Blueimp Jquery File Upload - upload files in different folders

Tags: jquery, file, codeigniter, upload, blueimp

I'm working with blueimp jquery file upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and want the ability to upload files to a folder on the basis of the URL. For example. If the url is: http://www.example.com/folder/**12345678abc**, i want to create a folder called '**12345678abc**', but nothing seems to work.

What i have tried so far is put this code in the constructor of **UploadHandler.php**:

```
$this->map = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (!file_exists('files/'.$this->map[2].'')) { mkdir('files/'.$this->map[2].''); }
```

Image of the script:
[image: Image:]

This works for a normal page, but if you put this in the **UploadHandler.php** file, you get the script path, not the URL. So it creates a folder called '**server**'. (this is the folder which holds the application)

Comment: which PHP library/framework/cms you are trying this in?

Comment: I'm building this in CodeIgniter

Comment: are you getting the name from the URL with ``$this->map``? You can use this in CI ``$this->uri->segment('2')`` to get the folder name. Then you need to give absolute path till your ``files`` folder

Comment: Yes, i've tried that, but it's not completely integrated with CodeIgniter, so it doesn't recognize CI commands. I've integrated many apps before, but i don't know how to that with this app....

Comment: Why you are adding ``.' '`` here: ``if (!file_exists('files/'.$this->map[2].'')) { mkdir('files/'.$this->map[2].''); }``
Remove this and first get full path till this ``files`` folder. You are on windows or linux?

Comment: Done that, it now creates the dir 'third_party'. I'm on Windows.

Comment: I think i'm going to follow this tutorial: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-9.5-with-CodeIgniter-2.1.4

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working by setting a cookie.

Controller:

```
setcookie("DIR", $this->uri->segment(3), 0, "/");
if (!isset($_COOKIE['DIR'])) { echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=".base_url()."upload/map/".$this->uri->segment(3)."'>"; }
```

UploadHandler.php:

```
$dir = $_COOKIE["DIR"];
if (!file_exists("../../../../resources/files/$dir")) { mkdir("../../../../resources/files/$dir"); }
```

Then i can set the upload dir:

```
'upload_dir' => "../../../../resources/files/$dir/",
```